# Create complex-type variables for a Web Service Task

Tags: web-services, ssis

In SSIS, I already have a Web Service Task using a WSDL for sending SMS. I am indeed able to send SMS using this task.

I want supply values to this task from the database, such as Mobile Number, Message body, User ID, etc.

**How can I create a complex type user variable that can be passed as input to a Web Service task?**

Comment: Yes. Find a web service that does that for you, get it's WSDL and have a go at it. When you have a problem post back.

Comment: using wsdl it worked for me but, i want to give values to the attributes as SSIS variables !

Comment: Post what you've tried so far. You should be able to use expressions to alter various things at runtime but some components don't support this very well. You might need to use a script task instead.

Comment: I also would like to know the answer.  Using the Web Service task, I see a way to pass in a variable, but not how to create a variable.  It seems like it expects a "complex type", but I am not sure how to build a complex type via any other task, even a Script task.  I have tried setting up the web service task and passing it literal values from the SSIS UI, but I cannot figure out how to build a variable to pass in.

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski If it's not a base type, then complex type must be of type Object. The web service task is ... lacking. If it's not immediately apparent how to make it do a thing, skip it and write a Script Task. You'll have far better control over what it does. This explained what a [complex type was](http://www.devtoolshed.com/content/building-web-service-aspnet-35). Your challenge boils down to how do I write a thing that gets info back from there, yeah? Do you need it as a WCF or will the old way of consuming web services aka, what I half remember suffice?

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing, pass a complex type value to a input variable used by a Web Service Task in SSIS, seeing as how I could not find a solution on the web including not finding a solution on stackoverflow.com, I am guessing the only possible solution is to invoke the web service directly using C# in a Script Task, if someone knows another way, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the only answer is to change the web service to accept only simple types as parameters.  I have scoured the web and there seems to be no way to dynamically create complex types for consumption by the input values in the web service task.

Answer (score 1):

The more 'easy' way is to use the script component for bypassing variables to a web service. Check http://amolpandey.com/2016/09/26/ssis-script-task-to-obtain-geo-cordinates-from-address-text-via-google-api/ & http://www.sqlmusings.com/2011/03/25/geocode-locations-using-google-maps-v3-api-and-ssis/.
Tested and working. Using this task you can bypass the SSIS variables/parameters.
Example: Getting ID, addreess, zipcode, city, country from a table with an execute SQL Task. Change Resultset:Full result set on General tab. Then on resultset tab add Result_Name:0 & Variable_Name: User::YourObject. Then the next task will be a Forlooptask editor (Foreach ADO Enumerator ,Collection tab - Ado object source variable: User::YourObject, enumeration mode: rows in the first table, variable Mapping tab - Variable User::Id, 0 | address,1 etc.). Inside the Forlooptask editor you add a data flow task, which the source of this task will be a script component. If you be more specific about your logic,we may assist you more.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I came across the same problem. I needed to pass one parameter as complex type.

1. Create a Web Service task in your package.
2. Fill all the needed properties at **General** tab: HttpConnection and WSDFile
3. Fill properties in **Input** tab: Service, Method
4. Below click on **Value**, manually enter the value you need (mine is 2021-11-15)
5. Deploy and execute package to be sure everything is OK

After this easy steps go into folder where package is localated. Right click on package file (**Package.dtsx**) and select Open with > Notepad. With find function in notepad search the value you manually inserted.
The part which we are looking for looks in my case like this

```
                  <WSTask:ComplexValue>
                    <WSTask:ComplexProperty
                      WSTask:Name="date"
                      WSTask:Datatype="dateTime"
                      WSTask:ParamType="Primitive">
                      <WSTask:PrimitiveValue>2021-11-15</WSTask:PrimitiveValue>
                    </WSTask:ComplexProperty>
                  </WSTask:ComplexValue>
```

Finally I found what I was looking for. Now for the second part I needed to be that parameter changing by current date when I execute that package. In powershell I managed to write a code that change date part in string: `<WSTask:PrimitiveValue>2021-11-15</WSTask:PrimitiveValue>` to current date, everytime when the package is executed. The code looks like this:

```
$Now = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd"    
$Yesterday = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$file = ((Get-Content -path "C:\Package.dtsx" -Raw) -replace "<WSTask:PrimitiveValue>$Yesterday</WSTask:PrimitiveValue>", "<WSTask:PrimitiveValue>$Now</WSTask:PrimitiveValue>")
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllText("C:\Package.dtsx",$file)
# This part will execute the package #
dtexec.exe /f "C:\Package.dtsx"
```

After all this, I planned this script in Task Scheduler and it works.
In my case changing the type of request from **complex** to **simple** wasn't an option and all I needed was just one parameter to pass.
Hopes it gonna help somebody.