# SSIS Web Service Task XmlNode Input POSSIBLE?

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, ssis

I've scoured the internet for the past two weeks and tried so many different ways that I'm beginning to think this might not be possible via a web service task in SSIS. I've created a web service task in SSIS by using a provided WSDL - see screenshot below.

[image]

As you can see the requirement for this web service method is to pass in an XML node which contains filter items like so:

```
<FilterItems><FilterItem FilterItemId="12345">4/20/2015 12:00:00 AM</FilterItem></FilterItems>
```

This "FilterItems" node is to be nested in between another XML element named "TemplateValues" - see soap body:

```
<soap:Body>
<GetReportResults xmlns="https://service.service.com">
  <username>string</username>
  <password>string</password>
  <reportId>int</reportId>
  <templateValues>xml</templateValues>
</GetReportResults>
```

The problem I'm facing is that when I go to chose a data type in the variable list in SSIS, there is no XML data type so I have to use a string.  The funny part is that I can use SOAPUI and call the same method with no issues just by passing in:

```
<FilterItems><FilterItem FilterItemId="12345">4/20/2015 12:00:00 AM</FilterItem></FilterItems>
```

Here is the SOAPUI call that I am able to use:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"      xmlns:ser="https://service.servicename.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
       <ser:GetReportResults>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:username>username</ser:username>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:password>12343</ser:password>
         <ser:reportId>000</ser:reportId>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:templateValues>
            <FilterItems><FilterItem FilterItemId="12345">4/20/2015 12:00:00      AM</FilterItem></FilterItems>
         </ser:templateValues>
      </ser:GetReportResults>
    </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

As you can see, I've just pasted the xml in between the  element and SOAPUI processes the request with no problem - so why can't SSIS web service task process this same request?

My thoughts are that since SSIS is forcing me to use a string variable to store the xnlNode that certain characters are being parsed.  Here are the results of the variable when I debug and run the web service task:

```
        Value   <FilterItems><FilterItem FilterItemId=\"12345\">4/20/2015 12:00:00 AM</FilterItem></FilterItems>
```

The debugging results show that the quotes have been escaped and I believe this is part of the problem.  Here are some other things I've tried:

Passing in entirely encoded XML(also tried using CDATA):

```
&lt;FilterItems&gt;&lt;FilterItem FilterItemId=&quot;12345&quot;&gt;4/20/2015 12:00:00 AM&lt;/FilterItem&gt;&lt;/FilterItems&gt;
```

I also tried creating a SQL task and when executed would grab the xml and add it to a variable.  Once again at runtime, escape characters were added in for the quotes causing the method not to execute.  I'm finding it hard to believe that this is not a common issue and there isn't an easy workaround to passing in XML into a web service task.  Is this a fault in SSIS or just something that hasn't been implemented?  Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the only answer is to change the web service to accept only simple types as parameters. I have scoured the web and there seems to be no way to dynamically create complex types for consumption by the input values in the web service task.

See also: [Create complex-type variables for a Web Service Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23626081/create-complex-type-variables-for-a-web-service-task)

Comment: Yes I believe you are correct.  I ended up writing a script task is SSIS using a SOAP envelope and was successful calling the web service.