# Passing complextype variables into SSIS Web Service Task

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to use a Web Service Task within SSIS to retrieve data from a 3rd party web service. The service requires complex types as input parameters. I need to be able to create a complextype variable and pass it in to the Web Service Task.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23626081/create-complex-type-variables-for-a-web-service-task

Comment: Web Service to me means SOAP message. It is a lot easier to build a SOAP XML string and use a script component to make the request using WebClient.UoloadString.